# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'model'. How to fix this error?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I'm new to Django. Please help me to solve this error. I'm not getting any solution. I tried many stackoverflow solutions and GitHub solutions but I'm not getting where the error is coming from.

urls.py

```
# from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from user_profile.views import UserProfileViewSet, CoursesViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', UserProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'courses', CoursesViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))

]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Creating user profile model.
class Courses(models.Model):
    courses = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.courses

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    imgUrl = models.CharField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_description = models.TextField()
    university_college = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Courses, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from user_profile.models import Courses, UserProfile
from user_profile.serializers import UserProfileSerializer, CoursesSerializer
# Use these two when you'll create url of one class inside another class
# from rest_framework.decorators import action
# from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all(),
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class CoursesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Courses.objects.all(),
    serializer_class = CoursesSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from user_profile.models import Courses, UserProfile

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

class CoursesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Courses
        fields = '__all__'
```

Exception log

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run        
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Works\DjangoProjects\note_sharing_application_backend\note_sharing_application_backend\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('api/v1/', include('user_profile.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Works\DjangoProjects\note_sharing_application_backend\user_profile\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    router.register(r'user', UserProfileViewSet)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 54, in register
    basename = self.get_default_basename(viewset)
  File "C:\Users\tanmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 141, in get_default_basename
    return queryset.model._meta.object_name.lower()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Here is the github link of the app - [Django](https://github.com/TanmoyTSSaha/note_sharing_app_backend.git)

I tried many stackoverflow solutions but I am not understanding from where the error is coming from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but I think the issue is with extra commas in both the views, they make it act as a tuple, see it correctly so it should be:

```py
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class CoursesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Courses.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoursesSerializer
```

Kindly remove them.

Also, in `imgUrl` field there must be `max_length` in `UserProfile` model.